# p:schedule Incorrectly displays event in schedule which have identical start and end date-time

Tags: primefaces, fullcalendar

I create two events in schedule (PrimeFaces Schedule Demo) http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml

For event "1" create with parameter

```
From: 08/02/2016 06:00 To: 08/02/2016 06:00
```

And event "2"

```
From: 09/02/2016 06:00 To: 09/02/2016 07:00.
```

[image: PrimeFaces Schedule]

Why in schedule event "1" display more than "2"? How I can fix it?

Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you did not do some debugging and little experimentation to. First of all it **only** happens with events of 0 duration, not 'less than one hour' (corrected your title) In the response you'll see that, when you create a ***0 (zero)*** duration event, the start-date-time and end-date-time are reported correctly.

```jsf
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response id="j_id1">
  <changes>
    <update id="j_idt88:schedule"><![CDATA[{"events" : [
      {"id": "3fbce3ee-7747-4cef-8362-c8d08d004c6e","title": "Champions League Match","start": "2016-02-17T21:00:00+0200","end": "2016-02-18T00:00:00+0200","allDay":false,"editable":true},
      {"id": "df70f7f0-6806-49a8-8991-9b109c397757","title": "Birthday Party","start": "2016-02-18T14:00:00+0200","end": "2016-02-18T19:00:00+0200","allDay":false,"editable":true},
      {"id": "7415213a-d721-4ffd-a60a-d82e88528c78","title": "Breakfast at Tiffanys","start": "2016-02-19T10:00:00+0200","end": "2016-02-19T12:00:00+0200","allDay":false,"editable":true},
      {"id": "81c0149b-0850-4b90-a345-4e89a764a2a5","title": "Plant the new garden stuff","start": "2016-02-20T16:00:00+0200","end": "2016-02-22T16:00:00+0200","allDay":false,"editable":true},
      {"id": "8087111d-c559-4add-a498-2f3f58a02f0d","title": "MyNewEvent","start": "2016-02-16T12:30:00+0200","end": "2016-02-16T12:30:00+0200","allDay":false,"editable":true}]}]]>
    </update>
    <update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0">
      <![CDATA[5869453577302409685:-7766841559488939365]]>
    </update></changes>
</partial-response>
```

So it is the client side that **shows** this 0 duration event as a 2 hour event. It is easy to find out that this 'client-side' is in fact jquery-fullCalendar and with some little searching, you can find out that it has defaults, among which:

```jsf
defaultTimedEventDuration:"02:00:00"
```

The [documentation about this](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/defaultTimedEventDuration/) is clear. So since it is 'nonsense' to show a 0 duration event, it assumes there is no end date and the default kicks in (I did not debug into the fullCalendar.js file that PrimeFaces uses) and consequently it is ***visibly*** converted to a two hour event. So this is the answer **why**.

The answer on 'how to fix it' ***cannot*** be fully answered since you nowhere state what your expected behaviour is.

***Easiest solutions***:

- Prevent user adding events like this.
- Set default value to your required value when populating the model (submit time OR render time).

An additional option is more complex and not tried by me

But since it is clear now the default settings of the FullCalendar most likely play a rolw, they need to be overridden. Well, in the 5.3 PrimeFaces docs, there is on page 402 something mentioned called the `extender` attribute with the following definition

> Name of javascript function to extend the options of the underlying fullcalendar plugin.

So adding `extender="scheduleExt()` to the schedule

And creating a corresponding javascript function and populate it correctly (this is an example, I did not test it, try)

```jsf
function scheduleExt() {
   //this = schedule widget instance
   //this.cfg = options
   this.cfg.defaultTimedEventDuration:"02:00:00"
   };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! But, I didn't write 'less then one hour') I'm understood that event created correctly, but I confused why it displayed so. Your answer very helped me. Thanks!

Comment: "ends in one hour" is read like ends *within* one hour. Otherwise it would be definitely incorrect since it ended in 0 hours... And all this can be easily found out by 'debugging', looking at sources etc...

Answer (score 0):

if @Kukeltje solution is not work then make changes in primefaces.jar

```
primefaces /src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/schedule/schedule.js
```

find `defaultTimedEventDuration:"02:00:00"` then modify your default Time Duration as per your required. It's perfectly work for me.

**Note :** @Kukeltje solution is not work for me so I implement this on Primefaces 6.0 jar

Comment: Why should it not work? Older versions then 5.3? Newer ones? Please be specific (and I assume you encountered this, otherwise you would not have created this answer)

Comment: @Kukeltje your solution is not work for me so implement mine.

Comment: Thanks for stating the version explicitly now. Let try to reproduce in 6.0 and if so then find out why it does not work in PF 6.0.